# What is the proper way to write a regular expression to replace string values in Excel using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, excel, regex

I wrote the code below to iterate through columns C to E in an Excel worksheet, retrieve regular expressions from row 2, and attempt to find matches in each text string (tempText) in column A. If a match is found, it records the match in a specific cell in a different worksheet and replaces the matched expression with a corresponding value from row 1. So based on the image below, column B would have content

B2 - Between the City Centre ! the mall

B3 - Between King Avenue #

B4 - Between Jane Station ! the Park

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zh5Lx.png)

**Issue**: The replacements are not happening and it appears javascript is not recognizing the regular expression. I am not sure how it can be re-written
Here's my code

```
           var z = 1;
      for (let h = 3; h <= 5; h++) {    
        const RegXX = activeWorksheet.getRow(2).getCell(h).value;
        const regex = new RegExp(RegXX, 'gi');
        const match = tempText.match(regex);
        if (match) {
            var row3 = extracts2Worksheet.getRow(2);
            row3.getCell(z).value = match[0];
            
            //row3.getCell(z).value = txt_extracts[j];
          // write the match to the "Extracts-2" worksheet
        tempText = tempText.replace(regex, activeWorksheet.getRow(1).getCell(h).value);
            z++;
            row3.commit();
            activeWorksheet.getRow(i).getCell(1).value = tempText;

                               }
                           }
```

I have tried writing the regular expression in different ways but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you clarify what regular expression you were trying to use and a sample input/output in text format?

Comment: For example, I want to search/replace "and a point (\\d+) metres north of" within "Between the City Centre and a point 23.3 metres north of the mall" so the final output should be "Between the City Centre ! the mall"

The image I shared above gives more info

Comment: Is trying `\\\\d` helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Don't double the backslashes in your regexes in the spreadsheet; Excel cells aren't JavaScript string literals. In a regex the way to indicate a digit is `\d`, with one backslash; you just have to *type* it as `\\d` if you're putting it into a literal in Javascript code:

```
> console.log('\\d')
\d
```